# Multiple field names

Tags: etl, pentaho, pentaho-data-integration

I have a txt file, which I have to insert into a database.

My problem is that in some files I have header "customer_" instead of "customer".

I don’t know how to fix this in Pentaho. I’ve tried "select values" but I have no idea how it works.

My transformation for now : get file names -> csv file input -> tx file output -> table output.

Answer (score 0):

You have Metadata Injection capabilities built in Pentaho Data Integration, but just "any" file won't work, you need some kind of logic to determine that "customer_" or whatever you get maps to the "customer" column in the database.

Once you have the logic to build of the variations of possible columns in the origin file to columns in the table, you can inject that metadata to your transformation.